# Getting iterator handle in MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to try out `MonitoredTrainingSession`, but I also use several Dataset objects for train and validation sets. And to select the correct one, as the [manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) suggests I use string handles. But to pass the handle into a `feed_dict` while training, I need to evaluate it first. Like this:

```
handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
```

But when I do this in context of `MonitoredTrainingSession`, I get an error:

```
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

The way out, as I thought, was to create an `init_fn` for a `Scaffold` object which I pass into the session. But this didn't work out. If I try to run aforementioned code in the context `init_fn` is still get the same error.

As the documentation says about `init_fn`:

> A callable to run after the init op to perform additional initializations.

This makes me think that I'm radically wrong with the intended purpose of this callback, or Tensorflow misbehaves.

Could you help me to resolve this confusion.

My tensorflow version is `1.4.0`.

*UPDATE*

Adding a minimal example. The first block works, the second doesn't.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.range(20, 25)

input_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=())
input_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
    input_handle, dataset_a.output_types, dataset_a.output_shapes)

x = input_iterator.get_next()
plus_one = tf.add(x, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    iterator = dataset_b.make_initializable_iterator()
    handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

    res = sess.run(plus_one, feed_dict={input_handle: handle})
    print(res)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
    iterator = dataset_a.make_initializable_iterator()
    handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

    res = sess.run(plus_one, feed_dict={input_handle: handle})
    print(res)
```

Comment: can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. The idea is that I have to give up with using handles and instead create several iterator initializers (per each dataset).

The solution can look as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.range(20, 25)

input_handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=(), name='input')
input_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
    input_handle, dataset_a.output_types, dataset_a.output_shapes)

x = input_iterator.get_next()
plus_one = tf.add(x, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    iterator = dataset_b.make_initializable_iterator()
    handle = sess.run(iterator.string_handle())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

    res = sess.run(plus_one, feed_dict={input_handle: handle})
    print(res)


iterator = dataset_a.make_initializable_iterator()

iterator_init_op_a = iterator.make_initializer(dataset_a)
iterator_init_op_b = iterator.make_initializer(dataset_b)

x = iterator.get_next()
plus_one = tf.add(x, 1)

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator_init_op_a)
    res = sess.run(plus_one)
    print(res)
    res = sess.run(plus_one)
    print(res)
    sess.run(iterator_init_op_b)
    res = sess.run(plus_one)
    print(res)
    res = sess.run(plus_one)
    print(res)
```

If the dataset depends on additional data (for example as in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays) section), I can additionally feed the required data into `iterator_init_op_a`, when I evaluate it.